# 'No date part in '' found. when upgrading from Magento 1.9.0.x to 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, ce-1.9.2.2, date

I have recently done an upgrade to a currently live and active Magento store from 1.9.0.x to 1.9.2.2 and when attempting to add a customer via the front end registration form or accessing customer edit in the admin area I receive the following PHP error:

> No date part in '' found.

See:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:25:"No date part in '' found.";i:1;s:5013:"
#0 app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#1 app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(210): Zend_Date->set(false, NULL, 'en_GB')
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(546): Zend_Date->__construct(false, NULL, Object(Zend_Locale))
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php(91): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->storeDate('1', false, true)
#4 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml(37): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View->getStoreCreateDate()
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/chrisbra...')
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php(303): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/tabs.phtml(38): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View))
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/chrisbra...')
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#21 app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/chrisbra...')
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#29 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(151): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#30 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction()
#31 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#32 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#33 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:54:"/index.php/admin/customer/edit/id/14570/css/styles.css";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How can I solve this by not modifying the core or loosing any current data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just fixed an issue after this exact error happened to me. Not sure if it was an upgrade or not.

Regardless, it was because a big chunk of customers had `customer_entity` set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` - which Magento really had trouble parsing.

Nevertheless, I ran the following SQL query and it fixed it:

(Obviously back it up)

```
UPDATE `customer_entity`
    SET created_at = "2014-01-01 09:00:00"
    WHERE created_at =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```

Don't take this for granted. I set the date to at least a year before the site went live so as not to contradict with orders the customer may have made.

Hope that helps in some way :)

Answer (score 0):

File path : lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php

Replace below:

```
 $split = false;
    preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $number, $splitted);

    if (count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
```

With :

```
$split = false;
    preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $number, $splitted);


    if (!empty($number) && count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I created [a simple module](https://github.com/stagemteam/magento-customer-date-fix) which allows fixing the problem with all new customers on your Magento site.

Please read `REAMDE.md` for more details.